# Java Mac OS How do I get -XstartOnFirstThread to implement when launching from finder?

Tags: java, macos, swt

I've created a jar file that uses SWT for the UI.  When launching the jar file from finder it would return an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

I finally got it to launch from Terminal using

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar CommonDenom.jar
```

That's all well and good, but how do I implement the `-XstartOnFirstThread` switch when launching from finder? Is there a simple way to do this through the manifest or something or do I have to package a launch script?  if the latter, can someone show me how?  Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps use the Oracle [AppBundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler/pages/Home) to create a Mac application which can include options (see the Wiki page).

Comment: thanks greg.  The link seems to only show installation instructions.  Where do I get the jar they are talking about?

Comment: https://java.net/projects/appbundler/downloads